# ¿Cómo poder seguir con la musica si cierro app y no al cambiar de Activity?

Tags: java, android

Me explico... he leído mucho sobre esto pero no consigo entender ni tener el código sobre cómo hacer que mi aplicación tenga una cancion todo el rato y cuando pulse el "Home button" se me vaya la cancion y no siga la app ni muestre nada, es decir, yo pongo una cancion y que mientras esté dentro suene al cambiar de Activity y si salgo de la app, sea en la activity que sea, se me salga sin sonar nada.

He conseguido hacer mediante :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public MediaPlayer mp; 

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_activity2);

        mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this,R.raw.musica);  
        mp.start(); 
    } 

     public void onStop()
     {
        super.onStop();
       if(mp.isPlaying())
         mp.stop();
       else
       return;
     y también: 
 o ...

     public void onFinish()
     {
        mp.stop(); 
        finish();
}
```

Pero SIEMPRE SIEMPRE consigo o que: al salir de la app se me vaya el sonido  ( que es lo que busco muy bien pero TAMBIÉN SE ME VA EL SONIDO AL CAMBIAR DE ACTIVITY) pues android creo que no diferencia entre home button y pasar de activity entonces me lleva loco... he leido mucho en inglés sobre esto y nada.. Necesito ,resumiendo, una ayuda sobre como hacer que si tengo 5 activitys y voy cambiando entre ellas esté 1 misma cancion y que al cerrar la App se me vaya el sonido y todo.

Answer (score 1):

Te sugiero revises primeramente el ciclo de vida de la `Activity`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/stopping.html

Puedes notar que cuando abres otra `Activity`, se ejecuta `onPause()` y posteriormente `onStop()`.

Por lo tanto el problema es que al ejecutarse el metodo `onStop()` estas deteniendo la reproduccion, te recomiendo eliminarlo si es que deseas que al cambiar de `Activity`, continue la reproduccion.

```
public void onStop()
 {
    super.onStop();
   if(mp.isPlaying()) //Si se esta reproduciendo.
     mp.stop();  //Detiene la reproduccion.
   else
   return;
}
```

En cuanto al metodo `onFinish()` este es llamado cuando ejecutas `finish()` deseando cerrar la Activity y la reproduccion en el `MedioPlayer` se detiene.

```
 public void onFinish()
 {
    mp.stop(); //Detiene la reproduccion.
    finish();
}
```

Comment: Lo he leído y hecho, pero se me sigue saliendo la musica cuando cambio de activity. ¿ Es imposible entonces que la música esté sonando todo el rato entre activitys (la misma musica) y que al salir de la app se apague ? Es que me estoy volvienvo loco ya llevo muchisimas horas perdidas...

Comment: Cuando cambias  de activity estas realizando el cierre con finish()?